# Laravel excel Import when header have merged cells

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

It seams that http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs can't figure out how to handle simple merged cells.

Importing excel file like this:

```
Excel::load($tmp_path, function($reader) {
  $reader->dd();
})->get();
```

See image bellow where is problem:

[image]

Comment: Have you gone through this: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked configuration and we can set 'slugged_with_count' in heading, so results become like picture bellow. Or disable heading and rely on columns order.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to read this file out differently, you can't use the simple import methods. You have to read it out per coordinate, example of the native PHPExcel methods:

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/phpexcel_library/1.7.4/manual.html#_Toc237519900

Also you can check the link: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/442

Hope this helps.